# What are some ways to speed up an img swap in jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a slightly vague question. I have the following in my code: http://jsfiddle.net/PMnmw/2/

In the jsfiddle example, it runs smoothly. The images are swapped quickly and without any hassle. When it is in my codebase though, there is a definite lag.

I'm trying to figure out why that lag is happening. The structure of the jquery is exactly the same as above. I.e. Inside the $(document).ready (...) function, I have a check to see if the user clicked on the img (based on the classname) and then I execute the same code as in the jsfiddle.

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what to do here... Clearly I'm not doing the swap right, or I'm being very heavy handed in doing it. Prior to this, one of my colleagues was using AJAX to do the swap, but that seems to be even more heavy duty (a full fledged get request to get the other icon...).

Comment: you can try `$(children[0]).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/c0fuZ.png")` instead of hiding and showing, just change image source. Not sure if that helps tho, it works smooth both ways for me.

Comment: The DOM is extremely small in the jsfiddle example code and the parent().children() call overhead will be minor. Without seeing your code that I assume is more involved would take longer. Can you do a hide/show pair based on ids or data-ids instead of parent/child?

Comment: Well, I was GOING to say it was a preloading issue, but you've done that already.  You can use Firebug or other developer tools to trace through the JavaScript to see what it's actually doing in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images that are not visible are normally not loaded by the browser before they are made visible. If there seems to be a problem, start by downloading an image optimizer like RIOT or pngCrush to optimize your images.
If it's only two arrows, you should consider joining them into a CSS sprite.

You could try not doing everything with jQuery, but it shouldn't really make that much difference.

Something like this maybe, with the hidden image loaded in JS and some traversing done outside jQuery (but that is probably not the problem, although the code seems overly long for a simple image swap?) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img=new Image();
        img.src='http://i.imgur.com/ZFSRC.png'; //hidden image url

    $(".wrapper").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.className=='toggle_img') {
           $('.toggle_img').toggle();
           if (e.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].style.display=='none') {
              console.log("hello");
          } else {
              console.log("goodbye");
          } 
        }
    });    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PMnmw/13/)
​

Comment: Will a CSS sprite decrease the loading time? I just checked on chrome -- just having the img tag ensures that the image is preloaded. Even though the display is set to none, the image is still downloaded to my machine.

Comment: Yes it will! Having both arrows in one image will make sure they are both loaded, and just changing the background position will be faster than changing the image source or changing elements. Also it will only need one request to the server to download instead of two, so it will speed up loading in pretty much all regards, and this is a perfect case for a sprite.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PMnmw/12/

Things I've optimized:

1. Created a variable for both `img1` and `img2`, so that you won't have to navigate the DOM to reference those two images anymore, thusly improving performance.
2. Applied a click handler to the images themselves, so you don't have to search the children of the wrapper.
3. The basic idea was to reduce the number of jquery selections as much as possible.

Let me know if this helped speed things up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img1 = $('#img1');
    var img2 = $('#img2');

    $(".toggle_img").click(function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if(target.is(img1)){
             img1.hide();
             img2.show();
        }
        else if (target.is(img2)) {
            img2.hide();
            img1.show();
        }
    });
});
```